# Storing an image into the SQLserver in windows store app

Tags: c#, sql-server, winrt-xaml

I'm new to windows 8 app development. I'm using XAML and C# for it. I'm using file picker to select an image. Now i want to store this image onto the SQLserver database. But the problem is there is no way to convert image into bytes in Store apps. And when i used WCF to do the same i'm having path issues because the service has been hosted somehwere else. Any link or help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello I tried to search and I think this might help you. If you have any other question feel free to ask. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f71da4cd-6f7b-4ddb-b2ed-1fb7a42e0117/adding-picture-to-sql-server-2000

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

public async Task<byte[]> GetBytesFromFile(StorageFile file)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];
        using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
        }
    }

    return fileBytes;
}
```

Comment: Hey Xyroid. Thank you man. I did it somewhat like this only. I just saw your answer. Thanks. :)